# Trigonometric functions separates the points

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Consider $s_n(x) := e^{inx}$ for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, and define ${\cal A} := span\{s_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$, I think there is a theorem says that ${\cal A}$ is dense in $(C([-\pi,\pi],\mathbb{C}),||\cdot||_{\infty})$

To prove this theorem, we need to invoke ***Stone-Weistrass Theorem***, one thing I don't understand is that why ${\cal A}$ separates the points over $[-\pi,\pi]$? For any $f \in {\cal A}$ we must have $f(-\pi) = f(\pi)$ right?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an excellent catch. Indeed, the trigonometric polynomials are dense in the space of *periodic* functions on an interval. Meaning that actually, trig polynomials are dense in the space
$$
\left(C(S^1,\mathbb{C}),||\cdot||_\infty\right)
$$

Comment: What does $S^1$ mean? Thanks!

Comment: @FailAnalysis it is the circle. This is encoding the fact that we only want functions $g$ with $g(-\pi)=g(\pi)$

Comment: Would you mind providing more details about proving that ${\cal A}$ is dense in ${C([-\pi,\pi])}$? Thanks!

Comment: Again, it's not. You need periodicity.